# Can't login into webmin on a VPS

Tags: ubuntu, users

I bought a VPS server, and I have installed webmin on it.
When I want to login to webmin via:

```
 http://88.198.196.118:10000/
```

it will redirect me to:

```
 https://static.88-198-196-118.clients.your-server.de:10000/
```

I tried to login with my SSH username and password (which I use to connect my server with SSH using putty) but I can't do it.

How can I log in to webmin?

Answer (score 2):

Your SSH username and password are not necessarily going to work with webmin, unless your host configured it that way.  Contact your host to find out what the webmin username and password is, then login with those credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You can login to:

```
https://88.198.196.118:10000/
    ^
```

Use the https scheme.